# What is wrong with this OpenXML?

Tags: sql-server, openxml

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSingersGenere
(@SingerData ntext)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @hDoc int      
    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,@SingerData


    IF OBject_id('SingerTable') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE SingerTable

    END

    CREATE TABLE SingerTable
    (
    SingerName varchar(200)
    )

    INSERT INTO SingerTable 
    (
    SingerName
    )
    SELECT * FROM OpenXML (@hDoc,'/Singers/Singer')
    WITH (SingerName varchar(200)) XMLSinger

    SELECT * FROM SingerTable
END
```

and the way I am executing is this:-

```
EXEC GetSingersGenere
 '<Singers>
<Singer>
Joe
</Singer>
<Singer>
ACDC
</Singer>
</Singers>'
```

I see NULL getting inserted in the table. Could anyone point out the mistake?

Comment: I don't know much about OpenXML, but from an XPath perspective, did you try `SELECT * FROM OpenXML (@hDoc,'/Singers/Singer/text()')`? Your XPath selects elements... maybe the select doesn't convert them to their text contents unless you explicitly ask it to.

Comment: Which OpenXml are you talking about? The format used by Microsoft Office? Then I don't see how this is related to your SQL query. Can you add more details please?

Comment: @0xA3, I am talking about the OpenXML statement in Sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the OPENXML will look at attribute values or child elements for the data.  If you write your select as:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenXML (@hDoc,'/Singers/Singer')
    WITH (SingerName varchar(200) 'text()') XMLSinger
```

It should work ok.  Note the addition of 'text()' in to the schema mapping to specify that we just want the text value of the node instead of any attribute value.

Comment: +1, definitely works. I totally missed the "text()" part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why even bother with the clunky OpenXML stuff?? Just use the basic XQuery support in SQL Server to do this much more elegantly:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetSingersGenre(@SingerData XML)
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.SingerTable(SingerName)
      SELECT
         Singer.Node.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
      FROM
         @SingerData.nodes('/Singers/Singer') AS Singer(Node)
```

Comment: @ydobomai: not sure - depends a lot on your XML, the size, structure, and your hardware. Try it! Try both approaches and measure - that's the only reliable way to know....